# Inexplicable stack overflow

Tags: c#, stack, stack-overflow, bloomberg

I have a code in C# that throws a stack overflow exception. It goes through the for loop 2485 times before happening, but securityDataArray.NumValues is 7234. I don't think I am having any recursion in this code, so I'm stucked, I dont understand why this happen. Is there any workaround?

If you need the full code, it comes from here : http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2012/11/a-nicer-net-api-for-bloombergs-open-api.html

```
var securitiesFields = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

//Loop through each security
for (var i = 0; i < securityDataArray.NumValues; i++)
{
    //First take out the security object...
    var security = securityDataArray.GetValueAsElement(i);

    var securityName = security.GetElementAsString("security");
    //... then extract the fieldData object
    var fieldData = security.GetElement("fieldData"); //The stack overflow exception is thrown here

    //If we need to add a new security to the securitiesFields dictionary then do so
    Dictionary<string, object> results = null;
    if (!securitiesFields.ContainsKey(securityName))
        securitiesFields.Add(securityName, new Dictionary<string, object>());

    //Get the fieldsByDate dictionary from the securitiesFields dictionary
    results = securitiesFields[securityName];

    //Extract results and store in results dictionary
    foreach (var dataElement in fieldData.Elements)
    {
        var dataElementName = dataElement.Name.ToString();
        results.Add(dataElementName, dataElement.GetValue());
    }
}
return securitiesFields;
```

(Part of) the call stack is :

```
BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 105 + 0xffffffd7 octets   C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.GetElement(string name) Ligne 99 + 0xe octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 85 + 0xf octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 132 + 0xb octets  C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.GetElement(string name) Ligne 99 + 0xe octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 85 + 0xf octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 132 + 0xb octets  C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.GetElement(string name) Ligne 99 + 0xe octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 85 + 0xf octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 132 + 0xb octets  C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.GetElement(string name) Ligne 99 + 0xe octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 85 + 0xf octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 132 + 0xb octets  C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.ReferenceDataRequest.ReferenceElementSecurityData.GetElement(string name) Ligne 99 + 0xe octets C#
    BEmu_csh.dll!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element.this[string].get(string name) Ligne 85 + 0xf octets C#
```

Comment: What line is the exception happening on? And can you post the call stack at that point? Most StackOverflowExceptions are anything but inexplicable but, since you're not showing any method definitions, there's not enough code to diagnose it. Other obvious questions are: what's the name of the method that this code is from, and how is `securityDataArray` defined?

Comment: It happens on the line "var fieldData = security.GetElement("fieldData");"
And Visual Studio says that the call stack is unavailable, because of the overflow

Comment: @MarinD - please [tag:edit] your question and highlight the line, and, as Dan suggests, also please include the stack trace.

Comment: And please include your method definition. And the definition of the class of the `security` variable, and the GetElement() method.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic:
`Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`

Comment: So, from what I can tell, you're using the Bloomberg Labs API, and the call is to [this method](http://static.bloomberglabs.com/api/dotnet/doc/3.8/html/M_Bloomberglp_Blpapi_Element_GetElement_2.htm). That's going to be either an error in the API, or possibly (depending on where your data has come from) a cyclic data source.

Comment: I've added the Bloomberg tag based on the content of your question; please feel free to remove if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @Dan Puzey Thank you for your help. You're right, it is Bloomberg related. The data source is static, so I don't think it can be a cyclic data source. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Binkan Salaryman I have added a link for the context. And this code portion is used by many other people, so this error can happen to them

Comment: You still haven't posted the stack trace; you'll need that to diagnose the problem. As I said, this issue is either an API bug (i.e. you need to raise a support call) or the data source is causing it (i.e. is cyclic in some manner when processed by the API). What do you mean by "the data source is static?"

Comment: @MarinD: After analyzing the main code there can be stackoverflow exception only on while loop which is waiting for all things to be done and when the event type is not falls on the one mentioned(Event.EventType.RESPONSE or Event.EventType.PARTIAL_RESPONSE) and can you debug that code part?

Comment: I edited my question to add the call stack. But it is the stack before the exception occurs. After, it becomes unavailable, as I said. About the static data source, forget it, I did not understand what you meant by "cyclic datas source"

Comment: I found something very strange. I get this exception when I fetch the field of a security with name ZAG000003699. I removed it from my query, and the program worked again, for more than 5300 securities. And then, it got the exception for another security, with name ZAG000019878. It seems that names that begin with ZAG makes the program go into an inifinte recursion... But I don't understand why, and how to fix this (except by removing these securities, which I cannot afford)

Comment: Your callstack as posted doesn't include the method that you say is causing the issue, so it can't be right. If you debug the application and enable "break on exceptions" you should be able to post the stack at the point where it breaks (and you'll most likely see a great long stack with a massively repeated section).

Comment: Ok, I managed to find it, I edited my question